# viber does not appear in "complete action using" list in android application?

Tags: android, android-intent, viber

My app should have to call mobile or telephone number by using any app installed in Android phone.  So I am using `ACTION_CALL` `Intent` as mentioned below.

```
private void OpenPhoneDialer(String number) {

    Log.i(TAG, "open phone dialer method called here " + number);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+"+"+number));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I get Skype, phone dialer as options in my complete action using popup. But Viber does not appear in this list. How to add Viber in complete action list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Viber - it is not responding to the ACTION_CALL intent that you are using.

You can view the AndroidManifest.xml file inside the Viber app to see what intents it does respond to if you want to have it show up.

One way to view the manifest is to use [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective) (which I wrote) to view the file installed on your device.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response.I am waiting any other comments for showing viber in list.